# Facebook Open Graph with JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook, sdk, socialshare

Are Open Graph tags necessary when using the JavaScript SDK UI API, provided by Facebook? My understanding is that the FB crawler reads the open graph tags to use as content for the post being shared. However, the SDK provides options where you can specify these. How do these work with each other?

Facebook will use the following (from the JS SDK) over the OG tags:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  display: 'popup',
  href: 'https://url.com',
  quote: 'Im a quote!'
});
```

Comment: Facebook doesn't use what you specify in the SDK. It only uses the tags.

Comment: Updated post:  Facebook will use what's specified in the SDK object over the OG tags.